# Working with Mouse Hover/Leave Event

Tags: c#, mouseevent

I have a `textbox` named `TxtHelp` with an initial text.
Also I have some `RadioButtons`.

When I fire the event `Mouse_Hover` I want to change the `TxtHelp.Text` to a custom text.
When I fire the event `Mouse_Leave` I want to return the original text of `TxtHelp`.

I know how to do this, using `2` events for each tool, so if I have 4 RadioButtons, it will be `8` events. It's a lot of code. Would be like this code for `each` radiobutton I have:

```
private void rb_Serial_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    txt_Ajuda.Text = "CustomText different for each RadioButton";
  }
private void rb_Serial_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    txt_Ajuda.Text = "Return to the initial value of textbox";
  }
```

Is there a way to make it more `practical` ? Some way that would take me `less` code ?

Comment: Hi, did you try to link all the MouseHover event/MouseLeave event of your radiobuttons to the same methode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalize the event handlers.  You need to identify the radio button, so either use the control's name, or assign an identifying piece of data to each radio button's `Tag` property (in my example, a simple `Int32` value):

```
private void rb_MouseHover(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (Convert.ToInt32(((RadioButton)sender).Tag))
    {
    case 0:
        text1.Text = "Text for radio button 0";
        break;
    case 1:
        text1.Text = "Text for radio button 1";
        break;
    case 2:
        text1.Text = "Text for radio button 2";
        break;
    case 3:
        text1.Text = "Text for radio button 3";
        break;
    //etc...
    }
}

private void rb_MouseLeave(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (Convert.ToInt32(((RadioButton)sender).Tag))
    {
    case 0:
        text1.Text = "Original for radio button 0";
        break;
    case 1:
        text1.Text = "Original for radio button 1";
        break;
    case 2:
        text1.Text = "Original for radio button 2";
        break;
    case 3:
        text1.Text = "Original for radio button 3";
        break;
    //etc...
    }
}
```

With that, you simply assign the same two event handlers to every `RadioButton` and identify them within.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to explain in my comment to the question. This should work.

Comment: I updated it a bit...that first go at it was admittedly pretty sloppy.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Why the numbers?  Shall I set a number on each radiobutton's tag property? How could I get the Control's name ?

Comment: To match the example exactly, yes.  In designer for each RadioButton, put a single digit in the Tag property, such as 2.  Then, the code will work.  Or, your `switch` statements could simply look for the name of the RadioButton, such as `case "rb_Serial":`.

Comment: @DonBoitnott +1 !! Worked. Thank you !

Comment: You don't need the `Convert`, just `switch (((RadioButton)sender).Name)`.